# awk: More elegant way to filter a file with another one

Tags: bash, parsing, optimization, awk, bigdata

I've recently approached the incredibly fast awk since I needed to parse very big files.
I had to parse this kind of input...

```
ID   001R_FRG3G              Reviewed;         256 AA.
AC   Q6GZX4;
[...]
SQ   SEQUENCE   256 AA;  29735 MW;  B4840739BF7D4121 CRC64;
     MAFSAEDVLK EYDRRRRMEA LLLSLYYPND RKLLDYKEWS PPRVQVECPK APVEWNNPPS
     EKGLIVGHFS GIKYKGEKAQ ASEVDVNKMC CWVSKFKDAM RRYQGIQTCK IPGKVLSDLD
     AKIKAYNLTV EGVEGFVRYS RVTKQHVAAF LKELRHSKQY ENVNLIHYIL TDKRVDIQHL
     EKDLVKDFKA LVESAHRMRQ GHMINVKYIL YQLLKKHGHG PDGPDILTVK TGSKGVLYDD
     SFRKIYTDLG WKFTPL
//
ID   002L_FRG3G              Reviewed;         320 AA.
AC   Q6GZX3;
[...]
SQ   SEQUENCE   320 AA;  34642 MW;  9E110808B6E328E0 CRC64;
     MSIIGATRLQ NDKSDTYSAG PCYAGGCSAF TPRGTCGKDW DLGEQTCASG FCTSQPLCAR
     IKKTQVCGLR YSSKGKDPLV SAEWDSRGAP YVRCTYDADL IDTQAQVDQF VSMFGESPSL
     AERYCMRGVK NTAGELVSRV SSDADPAGGW CRKWYSAHRG PDQDAALGSF CIKNPGAADC
     KCINRASDPV YQKVKTLHAY PDQCWYVPCA ADVGELKMGT QRDTPTNCPT QVCQIVFNML
     DDGSVTMDDV KNTINCDFSK YVPPPPPPKP TPPTPPTPPT PPTPPTPPTP PTPRPVHNRK
     VMFFVAGAVL VAILISTVRW
//
ID   004R_FRG3G              Reviewed;          60 AA.
AC   Q6GZX1; dog;
[...]
SQ   SEQUENCE   60 AA;  6514 MW;  12F072778EE6DFE4 CRC64;
     MNAKYDTDQG VGRMLFLGTI GLAVVVGGLM AYGYYYDGKT PSSGTSFHTA SPSFSSRYRY
```

...filter it with a file like this...

```
Q6GZX4
dog
```

...to get an output like this:

```
Q6GZX4 MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVEWNNPPSEKGLIVGHFSGIKYKGEKAQASEVDVNKMCCWVSKFKDAMRRYQGIQTCKIPGKVLSDLDAKIKAYNLTVEGVEGFVRYSRVTKQHVAAFLKELRHSKQYENVNLIHYILTDKRVDIQHLEKDLVKDFKALVESAHRMRQGHMINVKYILYQLLKKHGHGPDGPDILTVKTGSKGVLYDDSFRKIYTDLGWKFTPL    256
dog    MNAKYDTDQGVGRMLFLGTIGLAVVVGGLMAYGYYYDGKTPSSGTSFHTASPSFSSRYRY    60
```

To do this, I came up with this code:

```
   BEGIN{
    while(getline<"filterFile.txt">0)B[$1];
}
{
    if ($1=="ID")
        len=$4;
    else{
        if ($1=="AC"){
            acc=0;
            line = substr($0,6,length($0)-6);
            split(line,A,"; ");

            for (i in A){
                if (A[i] in B){
                    acc=A[i];
                }
            }
            if (acc){
                printf acc"\t";
            }
        }
        if (acc){
            if(substr($0, 1, 5) == "     "){
                printf $1$2$3$4$5$6;
            }
            if ($1 == "//"){
                print "\t"len
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

However, since I've seen many examples of similar tasks done with awk, I think there probably is a much more elegant and efficient way to do it. But I can't really grasp the super-compact examples usually found around the internet.
Since this is my input, my output and my code I think this is a good occasion to understand more of awk optimization in terms of performance and coding-style, if some awk-guru has some time and patience to spend in this task.

Comment: This may have been better on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An awk solution with a different field separator (in this way, you avoid to use `substr` and `split`):

```
BEGIN {
    while (getline<"filterFile.txt">0) filter[$1] = 1;
    FS = "[ \t;]+"; OFS = ""; ORS = "";
}

{
    if (flag) {
        if (len)
            if ($1 == "//") {
                print "\t" len "\n";
                flag = 0; len = 0;
            } else {
                $1 = $1;
                print;
            }
        else if ($1 == "SQ") len = $3;
    } else if ($1 == "AC") { 
        for (i = 1; ++i < NF;)
            if (filter[$i]) {
                flag = 1;
                print $i "\t";
                break;
            }
    }
}

END { if (flag) print "\t" len }
```

Note: this code is not designed to be short but to be fast. That's why I didn't try to remove nested if/else conditions, but I tried to reduce as possible the global number of tests for a whole file.
However, after several changes since my first version and after several benchmarks, I must admit that choroba perl version is a little faster.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $FILTER, '<', 'filterFile.txt' or die $!;
my %wanted;                # Hash of the wanted ids.
chomp, $wanted{$_} = 1 for <$FILTER>;

$/ = "//\n";               # Record separator.
while (<>) {
    my ($id_string) = /^ AC \s+ (.*) /mx;
    my @ids = split /\s*;\s*/, $id_string;

   if (my ($id) = grep $wanted{$_}, @ids) {
        print "$id\t";
        my ($seq) = /^ SQ \s+ .* $ ((?s:.*)) /mx;
        $seq =~ s/\s+//g;  # Remove whitespace.
        $seq =~ s=//$==;   # Remove the final //.
        print "$seq\t", length $seq, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but are you really sure this solution is faster then awk? I need to parse a >10 Gb file

Comment: Try to benchmark it. For me, it's definitely more readable, therefore maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of task, an idea is to pipe your second file through awk or sed in order to create on the fly a new awk script parsing the big file. As an example:

Control file (f1):

```
test
dog
```

Data (f2):

```
tree 5
test 2
nothing
dog 1
```

An idea to start with:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\/\1\/ {print $2}/' f1 | awk -f - f2
```

(where `-f -` means: read the awk script from the standard input rather than from a named file).

Comment: Sorry but I didn't really understand what you did there. Plus my "f2" is really different from that

Answer (score 1):

may not be much shorter than the original but multiple `awk` scripts will make the code simpler.  First awk generates the records of interest, second extracts the information, third formats

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{keys[$0];next} 
              {RS="//";
               for(k in keys) 
                  if($0~k) 
                     {print "key",k; print $0}}' keys file
| awk '/key/{key=$2;f=0;;next} 
        /SQ/{f=1;print "\n\n"key,$3;next} 
           f{gsub(" ","");printf $0} 
         END{print}' 
| awk -vRS= -vOFS="\t" '{print $1,$3,$2}'
```

will print

```
Q6GZX4  MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVEWNNPPSEKGLIVGHFSGIKYKGEKAQASEVDVNKMCCWVSKFKDAMRRYQGIQTCKIPGKVLSDLDAKIKAYNLTVEGVEGFVRYSRVTKQHVAAFLKELRHSKQYENVNLIHYILTDKRVDIQHLEKDLVKDFKALVESAHRMRQGHMINVKYILYQLLKKHGHGPDGPDILTVKTGSKGVLYDDSFRKIYTDLGWKFTPL       256
dog     MNAKYDTDQGVGRMLFLGTIGLAVVVGGLMAYGYYYDGKTPSSGTSFHTASPSFSSRYRY    60
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vim it's actually one-liner to find the pattern:

```
/^AC.\{-}Q6GZX4;\_.\{-}\nSQ\_.\{-}\n\zs\_.\{-}\ze\/\//
```

where `Q6GZX4;` is your pattern to find in order to match the sequence characters.

The above basically will do:

1. Search for the line with `AC` at the beginning (`^`) which is followed by `Q6GZX4;`.
2. Follow [across multiple lines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines) (`\_.\{-}`) to the line starting with `SQ` (`\nSQ`).
3. Then follow to the next line ignoring what's in the current (`\_.\{-}\n`).
4. Now start selecting the main [pattern](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_lines_not_containing_pattern) (`\zs`) which is basically everything [across multiple lines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines) (`\_.\{-}`) until (`\ze`) the `//` pattern if found.
5. Then execute normal Vim commands (`norm`) which selects the pattern (`gn`) and yank it into `x` register (`"xy`).
6. You may now print register (`echo @x`) or remove whitespace characters from it.

This can be extended into Ex editor script as below (e.g. `cmd.ex`):

```
let s="Q6GZX4"
exec '/^AC.\{-}' . s . ';\_.\{-}\nSQ\_.\{-}\n\zs\_.\{-}\ze\/\//norm gn"xy'
let @x=substitute(@x,'\W','','g')
silent redi>>/dev/stdout
echon s . " " . @x
redi END
q!
```

Then run from the command-line as:

```
$ ex inputfile < cmd.ex
Q6GZX4 MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVEWNNPPSEKGLIVGHFSGIKYKGEKAQASEVDVNKMCCWVSKFKDAMRRYQGIQTCKIPGKVLSDLDAKIKAYNLTVEGVEGFVRYSRVTKQHVAAFLKELRHSKQYENVNLIHYILTDKRVDIQHLEKDLVKDFKALVESAHRMRQGHMINVKYILYQLLKKHGHGPDGPDILTVKTGSKGVLYDDSFRKIYTDLGWKFTPL
```

The above example can be further extended for multiple files or matches.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks almost OK as-is. Keep it simple, single-pass like that.

Only a couple suggestions:

1) The business around the split is too messy/brittle. Maybe try it this way:

```
        acc="";
        n=split($0,A,"[; ]+");

        for (i=2;i<=n;++i){
            if (A[i] in B){
                acc=A[i];
                break;
            }
        }
```

2) Don't use input data in the first argument to your `printf`s. You never know when something that looks like printf formatting might come in and really mess things up:

```
printf "%s\t",acc";

printf "%s%s%s%s%s%s",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6;
```

Update with one more possible "elegance":

3) The `awk` style of `pattern{action}` is already a form of if/then, so you can avoid a lot of your outer if/then nesting:

```
$1="ID" {len=$4}
$1="AC" {
    acc="";
    ...
    }
acc {
    if(substr($0, 1, 5) == "     "){
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR == NR { aFilter[ $1 ";"] = $1; next }
   /^AC/ {
      if (String !~ /^$/) print Taken "\t" String "\t" Len
      Taken = ""; String = ""
      for ( i = 2; i <= NF && Taken ~ /^$/; i++) {
         if( $i in aFilter) Taken = aFilter[ $i]
         }
      Take = Taken !~ /^$/ 
      next
      }
   Take && /^SQ/ { Len = $3; next }
   Take && /^[[:blank:]]/ {
      gsub( /[[:blank:]]*/, "")
      String = String $0
      }
   END { if( String !~ /^$/) print Taken "\t" String "\t" Len }
         ' filter.txt YourFile
```

Not really shorter, maybe a bit more generic. The heavy part is to extract the value that serve as filter from the line